# Optimising my three level MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have an SQL detailed below and was hoping someone might be able to help me to optimise this a bit as I think it's a bit clunky...  Any help gratefully received, thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM test.datalist
Where UserName Like '%SearchString%'
Or UserName In (
                Select Synonym
                From synonyms
                Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%'
                OR ListRef = (  Select ListRef 
                                From synonyms
                                Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%')
                );
```

All suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: seems like query is written w/o given any thought what exactly needed in output. what is the difference if you apply same where filter in inner and outer query. "Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%'" unless innermost query you meat with filter "Where ListRef Like '%SearchString%'"

Comment: If you need to search in 2 tables and 3 columns for the same pattern, the db designer did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Below part of subquery makes no sense  while  you already matched with `Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%'` no use to find `ListRef` for same table to get `Synonym`

```
Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%'
OR ListRef = (  Select ListRef 
                                From synonyms
                                Where Synonym Like '%SearchString%')
```

otherway you can try join

```
SELECT * FROM datalist d
JOIN synonyms s ON (d.UserName =s.Synonym)    
Where d.UserName Like '%SearchString%' or s.Synonym Like '%SearchString%'
```

I have joined your table on basis of `d.UserName =s.Synonym` if you have a particular relation between these table apply that one ,and put proper index your columns

Comment: Thanks for the comments, perhaps I should explain the table structure as it's obviously not clear.  In the datalist table is a description column that contains free text entered by a user.  The second table is a two column table that lists synonyms of words and phrases so we have things like leaflet, brochure, handbill etc.

Comment: What the SQL does is return all description rows where either the SearchString is present or any of the listed synonyms of the search string.  So the second subquery makes perfect sense as it returns the ListGroup, the first subquery then returns all of the synonyms in that group and the main query return all of the descriptions that contain either the SearchString or any of the synonyms associated with that SearchString.